# masstransit 3 for rabbitmq typed exception not handled

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq, masstransit

I have an issue consuming Fault message, it not handled.
Handler code is:

```
internal class FaultConsumer : IConsumer<Fault<MyMessage>>
    {
        public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<Fault<MyMessage>> context)
        {
            var ctx = context;
            var sourceMessage = ctx.Message.Message;
            // ... processign
        }
    }
```

but If i creating non generic consumer it works fine, something like:

```
internal class FaultConsumerNonGeneric : IConsumer<Fault>
        {
            public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<Fault> context)
            {
                var ctx = context;
                // here I cannot get source message
            }
        }
```

Here is consumer register code:

```
var errorBus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(ebs =>
            {
                var host = ebs.Host(new Uri("rabbitmq://localhost/"), h =>
                {
                    h.Username("guest");
                    h.Password("guest");
                });
                ebs.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "error_handler", endpoint =>
                {
                    endpoint.Consumer(ConsumerFault);
                });
            });
errorBus.Start();
```

In adim panel I see a lot of typed fault messages that not been delivered to my FaultConsumer in error_handler queue, but MT created `error_handler_error` queue contains errors:
[see the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdLkH.png)

so the question is what i doing wrong? How to consume typed faults correctly? Thanks.

the example of message in rabbitmq:

```
Content-Type:   application/vnd.masstransit+json
MT-Reason:  fault
MT-Fault-Message:   Тип "DynamicInternal08d37bdc15c6c87e10c37bca6d210000.MassTransit.Fault<Consumer.MyMessage>" из сборки "MassTransitDynamicInternal08d37bdc15c6c87e10c37bca6d210000, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" пытается реализовать недоступный интерфейс.
MT-Fault-Timestamp: 2016-05-14T09:42:39.4976501Z
MT-Fault-StackTrace:    в System.Reflection.Emit.TypeBuilder.TermCreateClass(RuntimeModule module, Int32 tk, ObjectHandleOnStack type) 
в System.Reflection.Emit.TypeBuilder.CreateTypeNoLock() 
в System.Reflection.Emit.TypeBuilder.CreateType() 
в MassTransit.Internals.Reflection.DynamicImplementationBuilder.CreateTypeFromInterface(ModuleBuilder builder, Type interfaceType)
MT-Host-MachineName:    SHARPCODER-PC
MT-Host-ProcessName:    Consumer.vshost
MT-Host-ProcessId:  13024
MT-Host-Assembly:   Consumer
MT-Host-AssemblyVersion:    1.0.0.0
MT-Host-MassTransitVersion: 3.3.2.641
MT-Host-FrameworkVersion:   4.0.30319.42000
MT-Host-OperatingSystemVersion: Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0
```

Comment: If you look at one of the messages (using Get message in the RabbitMQ console) what is the error shown in the header section?

Comment: My problem about consumer does not receiving generic Fault messages

Comment: The screenshot you posted shows errors in the error Handler queue, I'm asking you to look at the headers of one of those messages to see Why the fault message was not consumed.

Comment: Sorry, not understand first. Look at question topic, I posted a one error

Comment: Can you add your message class definition? It seems there may be something it can't create, maybe it is internal or private and can't be created?

Comment: Thanks Chris! You are genius) `MyMessage` type was internal and MT just could not create its instance. I set public modifier and Fault consumer begin work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For MassTransit to be able to consume a Fault message, which is created when a consumer faults, the message type must be a public class that can be created as a generic Fault class. Otherwise, the fault cannot be consumed by your fault consumer.

You should also consume the Fault, not the consumer type:

```
public class YourMessage
{
}

public class MyConsumer :
    IConsumer<Fault<YourMessage>>
{
}
```